Can we connect Views in SAP HANA to Tableau Desktop?
Ok, so I think this is a simple question, but I would like to know that if I create some views in SAP HANA using SQL, and want to connect with Tableau, will those views be available, or does Tableau support SAP HANA views or we can only connect with tables and not views. Please clarify this doubt.
I am using the Tableau Desktop Built-in connector for SAP HANA. I have already created these views in the SAP HANA database using the SAP GUI console from the DBACOCKPIT transaction code in the SQL editor. I am just trying to confirm if those views created in the SAP can be accessed in Tableau Desktop for setting the connection.

Yes, Tableau supports SAP HANA views as data sources.
See the Tableau documentation for details.
Tableau uses the SAP HANA JDBC driver to connect to HANA, so this needs to be downloaded and copied into the right folder. You can just download the current JDBC driver from https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#hanatools for this.
Finally, in order to be able to see your views, the user account used for connecting to the SAP HANA DB must have the right permissions to SELECT from the views. Typically, you want to package those permissions into a role and grant the user that role.
There are multiple blogs and tutorials available on the SAP websites, for example this one: Connect Tableau to SAP Datasphere

Ok, Just confirm for me that Tableau supports the database views, created through the Hana SQL query editor using the CREATE VIEWS [NAME] AS {query} command. I am new to Tableau.

Yes, Tableau can use SQL views in SAP HANA DBs.
